# Why is the water in Pingualuit crater so pure?

Tags: lakes

The question [Is there a lake whose sole source of water is rain and has a hole at the bottom draining it?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/is-there-a-lake-whose-sole-source-of-water-is-rain-and-has-a-hole-at-the-bottom) doesn't have an answer that answers my question. Also, it has a mistake in it. According to the first comment under the body of the question [Is Oregon lake extremely pure water? If so, why?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18451/is-oregon-lake-extremely-pure-water-if-so-why), the lake in the video [Clear Lake, Oregon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRhMegxuT5w) and the lake in the video [Adventure Oregon - Lost Lake draining into a giant hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAMLGB0hUmk) aren't the same lake.

According to [this revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pingualuit_crater&oldid=927258451) the Wikipedia article Pingualuit crater which is also the current revision, "The lake also holds some of the purest fresh water in the world, with a salinity level of less than 3 ppm (the salinity level of the Great Lakes is 500 ppm)." I assume that all solutes except air have an extremely low concentration. I also assume that the dissolved air doesn't have a higher concentration at lower depths despite the higher pressure there because there are no compressed air pockets down there to dissolve into the water and is saturated only at the surface.

My question is

> Is it true that all the nongaseous solutes have a concentration by volume that's almost as low as that of salt? If not, approximately what is the concentration of the nongaseous solute with the highest concentration and what is that solute? Could the cause of the high purity be that Pingualuit crater is on high ground so the water is constantly soaking into the ground below draining solutes with it and getting replaced by rain water because there are no outlets to Pingualuit crater?

I realize that probably nothing is totally insoluble in water and so the surrounding rock probably dissolves to some extent.

Comment: Timothy, you now have asked eight questions and have accepted a grand total of zero answers. This gives us zero reason to answer your questions.

Comment: @DavidHammen Sometimes I find an answer kind of useful but feel that it doesn't go quite as far as solving my problem. Until recently, I never realized about the feature of accepting an answer. You can stop answering my questions if you want to but if I don't feel like an answer solved my problems, I'm not going to put a check mark beside it.

Comment: One more time, Clear Lake and Lost Lake are two different lakes. You have an incorrect view of many, many things and are unwilling to accept answers that indicates that this is the case.

Comment: @DavidHammen I guess I can see your point. You may be thinking I have no point in asking a question if I can't get an answer that solves my problem. I don't think that's quite correct although I'm less likely to ask one if I can't get an answer that solves my problem. I may possibly sometimes ask a question because I think it may be useful. I even sometimes ask and answer my own question because I think it's useful and Stack Exchange allows it. I believe the the underlying assumption in this question is true and if it got an answer confirming it, I probably would put a check mark beside it

Comment: because it would answer my question in a way that I can understand. I actually did put a check mark beside one of my questions on this website after you wrote a comment that I accepted none of the answers. I also accepted some answers on other Stack Exchange websites.